# Xamarin Studio Starter: Why am I getting native library reference error on build without native libraries?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I've been playing around with the Starter Edition of Xamarin Studio to determine if it will meet my needs. I understand (so I thought) the limitations of this edition; 32K compiled IL limit, no native libraries, etc. Now, I understand native libraries to be C/C++ libraries, or even native Java libraries. This does not seem to be the case.

I have a solution in Xamarin Studio with 2 projects. One is an Android Class Library, the other is an Android Application. When I reference the class library from the application project and build, I get the following error.

> Your app references native libraries. This functionality requires Indie Edition or higher.

I beg to differ! Every .cs file in the referenced Android class library project is simple .NET code. What am I missing? I can successfully run the Tasky Android_Starter solution without issue, and it is made up of 2 projects like mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to delete the Resources folder and manually edit the Android class library project file in order to get this working. I looked at the Tasky sample's project file as a reference.

After deleting the auto-included Resources folder from the project, edit the .csproj file in a text editor to remove the following XML elements:

- Project\ProjectGroup\AndroidResgenFile
- Project\ProjectGroup\AndroidResgenClass

With those things taken care of, I no longer get the error. I'm guessing, Xamarin Studio thought I was referencing another Android application instead of a class library. Not sure why the default project template includes things to break such a flow, but perhaps I'm not "doing" right" either. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the Resources folder and manually editing the csproj file didn't work for me. I had to create a new C# Library project instead of creating an Android Library Project and import my .cs files into that. After that it compiled and ran fine.